# Xamarin Form Project: Does Not Have A Dependency Folder

Tags: xcode, xamarin.forms, nuget

I've just created a new xamarin form project, but couldn't find the folder `dependencies` folder under my shared project, this folder usually below the `Getting Started` file.

This lead to I can't add the nuget package for my shared project.

I'm using visual studio 2017 and xCode 10.3

So how can I find this folder on the xamarin-form project?

[my project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TKZj.png)

Comment: You can firstly update the VS to 2019(8.3.x) and XCode to 11.0 .Then check if the issue still exists .

Comment: Thank you, I've used the vs2019, and it's the same issue.@Armin Rasoulian helped to point out in it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of xamarin forms code sharing strategy: .NET Standard and Shared Project. I guess that your project is of type Shared Project, which makes sense if there were no dependencies folder.

please read the following article:
https://medium.com/@daRochaPires/xamarin-pcl-vs-shared-project-a838806d5cc6

Comment: Thank you, so I think I should create another solution, which is .NET standard. But this seems blocked on my visual studio mac.